# Can not find Remote Shell in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to do some work for which I require **shell in eclipse** but I can't get it anywhere.

I have tried :
**Window > Show View > other**
but i didn't get any option over there.

Shall I download something for the shell, or do any settings to get the shell ?

Give any link.
Thank you.

Comment: Which shell you want?terminal?

Comment: Yes sir i want the terminal shell in which i want to put a command which will give me the **SHA1** number. Please tell me from where can i get it. I have downloaded **Mobile and Device Development** as the answer given by mr. greg-449. See the question i asked in comment in that answer. @Jeevan Roy dsouza

Comment: why you cant access using java code?

Comment: Because I dont know how to do that will you please tell me sir. I just want that **SHA1** number for my android application. @Jeevan Roy dsouza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Eclipse RSE (Remote System Explorer) installed for this support.

Go to `Help > Install New Software`, choose your Eclipse release to work with. RSE is in the `Mobile and Device Development` section.

Comment: Exactly sir, Thanks a lot. Actually I want to access Google drive from my android application so I want the shell to put the command and it will give me **SHA1** number. Please tell me how can I open that window in which i can put the command. Here is the link through which you will came to know what i exactly mean to say. [https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android] Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access using java code

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("//enter Your shell Command here");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
p.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line = reader.readLine();
sb.append(line);
while (line != null) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    sb.append(line);
    }
System.out.println(sb.toString());//ur shell command result
```